# In ASP.NET, i have a DataGridView Control, how can i add a edd button and how to plud code to that without use GUI, only through Programmee

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, webforms

In ASP.NET, i have a DataGridView Control, how can i add a edd button and how to plud code to edit, without useing GUI, only through Program

Comment: Start by making good use of Google Translate, then we will be glad to provide you clear answers to clear questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the commandfield class and can manually add the edit colum from in the code as below:

```
 CommandField field = new CommandField();
 field.ButtonType = ButtonType.Button;
 field.ShowEditButton = true;
 GridView1.Columns.Add(field);
```

Then handle the edit row event of the gridview. you can set all sorts of properties in the commandfield object like you do from the gui.